# Has anyone had output missing from a SQL Query Activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Some Subscribers are not showing up when I create a simple SQL Query activity?  I have tried the query with no 'Where' and no Joins.  Some subscribers are not showing up.  They are active in the All Subscribers List.

Comment: Can you find those subscribers in your source data extension after exporting it to FTP? Can you find them there with a filtered data extension?

Comment: Just tried a filtered data extension and the records were there... Why wouldn't they show up in my SQL Query Activity?

Comment: Do you have a different primary key in the resulting data extension? Keep in mind all we can do is take shots in the dark until you provide a sample of the query and data extensions you're working with.

Comment: Thank you!  I am going to look at my Primary keys - it may have something to do with that.  My SELECT statement is very simple (SELECT profile_ID, Last_Name, First_Name, Registration_Date FROM [Data_Extension_1])

Answer (score 1):

Are you performing this query in a child BU?

If yes, try to query using the `ent` prefix

```
select
  SubscriberKey
from ent._Subscribers
```

Comment: Good thought but the data is coming from another data extension that I created within the BU that gets overwritten daily.  I am basically trying to get a portion of that data extension to target for an email send.

Comment: Please can you post the query and Target Data Extension field names? It's a good thing to check, if the field name is wrong in your query (in the select to the target Data Extension), you don't receive erro message, the data is simply "ignored"

Comment: Also a good idea - Thanks for your response.  I know the target data extension is correct because I am getting data inserted into it - just not all of the data that I expect.  For some reason, it is excluding records.  I have also tried the query with no where clause and there is no join in the SQL Statement.